# Spring Security 3.2.2 Logout Redirecting to Wrong Page

Tags: spring, web, spring-security

I have a logout button created which is set up and works, but it's redirecting to my invalid-session-url for some reason. Relevant bit of the security.xml:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <form-login login-page="/login"
                login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
                default-target-url="/view"
                always-use-default-target="true"
                authentication-failure-url="/login?redirect=login_error" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?redirect=logout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
    <session-management invalid-session-url="/login?redirect=session_timeout" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="isAnonymous()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
</http>
```

Not sure why this is happening. I have my session-timeout in web.xml set to 5.

Comment: Check whether the session cookie is actually deleted when you logout (debug the request/response traffic in your browser).

Answer (score 0):

When you logout the first thing that Spring Security does is to invalidates the session, so the invalid-session-url is used. You can set  `invalidate-session="false"` on the `logout` element or remove `<session-management invalid-session-url="/login?redirect=session_timeout" />`.

Comment: This isn't correct. The session management filter configuration doesn't affect logout behaviour. You almost always want the session invalidated when you logout.

Comment: @ShauntheSheep why spring `invalidSessionUrl("someurl")` is called right after a user logs in, I noticed this behavior because "someurl" is only used here, and the person is redirected to that url after he logs in.